# how to get Score of friends in circles google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-play-services, public

I want ranking Score of friends in circles google+, but i don't get Score of friends.

how to get Score of friends in circles google+ ?
please help me!

Comment: Can I ask what you've tried so far and what issues you've run into?

Comment: I've got friends list

but i don't know how get their score from leaderboard

Comment: public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
   PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
   try {
    int count = personBuffer.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     Log.i("g+", "id : " + personBuffer.get(i).getId());
     // i want get score of friend (personBuffer.get(i)) from leaderboard 
     // but I did not find any function to do that
    }
   } finally {
    personBuffer.close();
   }
 }

Comment: sorry for my bad english :D